# Spin - Spin interaction relations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-spin

I am confused about some math properties of spin that you might be able to shed some light on.

It is basically showing the following

$<\uparrow | \mathbf{S}\cdot\mathbf{s} | \uparrow > = \frac{1}{2}S_z$

This should be super easy. I might just be missing some basic math, to see how this is true. The whole setup I was looking at is electrons in metals moving freely with itinerant electrons. So basically

$| \uparrow >$ refers to the spinalong the z-axis for the intinerant electrons. $\mathbf{S}$ is the spin of the impurity spin and $\mathbf{s}$ is the spin density of the conductions electrons.

Any help on seeing how this is true, would be nice. Cheers

Comment: $\langle \uparrow |S_x|\uparrow \rangle = \langle \uparrow |S_y|\uparrow \rangle = 0$. So you find $\langle \uparrow |\mathbf{S}\cdot \mathbf{s}|\uparrow \rangle = \langle \uparrow |S_z s_z|\uparrow \rangle$. Let $S_z$ act at the bra (since $S_z^\dagger = S_z$), then $\langle \uparrow|S_z = \langle \uparrow|$ from which you see that $\langle \uparrow |s_z|\uparrow \rangle$ is left. Don't know what happens next. Maybe this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question has been hinted in the comment.The spin-1/2 operator for the itinerant (or conduction) electron, $\mathbf{s}$ has expectation $\langle \uparrow | s_{z} | \uparrow\rangle = 1/2$ and $\langle \uparrow | s_{x} | \uparrow\rangle = \langle \uparrow | s_{y} | \uparrow\rangle = 0$, where $| \uparrow\rangle$ is the eigenstate of the $z$-component of electron spin operator with e.v. $+\frac{1}{2}$. This can be simply used to show $\langle \uparrow | \mathbf{S}.\mathbf{s}| \uparrow \rangle = \frac{1}{2} S_{z}$, since the impurity spin doesn’t act on the electron spin state.